# Can't show status icon on system tray with gtk2.0 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk

I'm currently working on my small app with C and want to show a status icon in the upper right corner of the screen. I have tried `gtk_status_icon_new()` and `gtk_status_icon_new_from_stock()` and so on but nothing happened.

I also found some Python code: http://eurion.net/python-snippets/snippet/Systray%20icon.html, but this doesn't work either.

Any idea?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521006/wxtaskbaricon-in-ubuntu-12-10) may help here.